# Converting time with decimal separator to military time and copy to different sheet (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have to enter a lot of cycle times and having to use ":" inbetween was awful.  This info is being used in minitab so the format to enter is terrible.  I have to go across 26 columns on sheet1 to enter 16 cells of data.  Instead of scrolling everytime, I made a separate sheet (2) with the 16 cells of data in one colum so I can enter data on the numberpad only.  The format is hh.mm.  A macro then replaces the "." with ":" and copys it into sheet1 in the appropriate place.  everything else works fine but when hh.m0 is entered it is converted to hh.0m ex. (15.30 becomes 15:03 after macro is run) 15.34 is 15:34 after the macro though. If there are no zeros, the code works fine.   most of the code is below.   The pm and am worked fine but the people filling it out didn't put am and pm on the sheet so we are now using military. I'm open to completely different code but this is all I could think of.

Thank you

```
Set w1 = Sheets("Data Collection Sheet").Cells
Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells

For x = 8 To 15
Cells(x, 2).Activate
Cells(x, 2).Replace what:=".", replacement:=":"
'Cells(x, 2).Replace what:="p", replacement:=" pm"
'Cells(x, 2).Replace what:="o", replacement:=" am"


Next x 
w1(9, 3).Value = w2(9, 2).Value
'  I go on to make other cells the same value but this should give an idea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using code would be to use a formula:

`=TIME(INT(A1),(A1-INT(A1))*100,0)`

The numbers to the left of the decimal give you the hour. The decimal and anything trailing behind it gives you minutes which are then multiplied by 100 to get the integer value. Seconds = 0.

I think the minutes were giving you a problem due to excluding the decimal. `0.03` will give you `03` which then becomes `3`. `0.30` will also give you `3` because `0.3 = 0.30 = 0.300 = 0.30000`, and so on.

Comment: Your solution Works. Thank you very much. 15.3 or 15.30 would turn into 15:03 in my macro though. I don't understand why. Oh well

Comment: Glad it worked! As for the macro, it needs a way to know if it should be 3 or 30. For example, how would it know whether you want the value 30 as opposed to 300? Remember that 0.30 is the same number as 0.300. In the formula, this was being handled by including the decimal and multiplying it by 100. If you needed 300, you would multiply by 1000. Aaron used this same logic. Furthermore, I like that he used INT, so I edited my formula to use it too as it is also available in worksheet functions and it is a simpler way.

Comment: Sweet, your edited version solved another issue I just found.  h.00 gave an error (presumably because of the decimal going away).  The edited version outputs the right time though.  Thank you Nethy and Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Try the TimeValue function:

```
a = TimeValue("15.30")
```

If "15.3" is something you'll run across, you could check and change before the TimeValue statement:

```
a = 15.3 'the initial value
b = a - Int(a) 'b = the fractional part
c = (b * 10) - Int(b * 10) 'c = the 2nd digit out of
'the fractional part

If c > 0 Then 'something like mm.d has been
'put in instead of mm.dd
```

Comment: I tried this code and it didn't work.  Typing in a = timevalue("15.30") works but it isnt flexible enough                            Dim a As String

   a = TimeValue(Cells(1, 2))
   Cells(2, 2).Value = a